# What is this insect (Germany)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

It was hovering and in between it was very fast and hard to photograph. I'm not even sure if it is an insect? Photographed in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from your photo, but you should check whether [*Macroglossum stellatarum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummingbird_hawk-moth) (*German*: Taubenschwänzchen/ *English*: hummingbird hawk-moth) looks similar to what you've seen.

This moth is living in Germany (and other regions) and due to it's way of flying (hovering and audible humming) it's sometimes confused with a hummingbird.

Comment: Seems to be right. I tried hard to make a good photo but it was too fast and I never got it into the seeker fast enough...

Comment: @mike I've seen it once and fully understand that it's hard to take a proper picture :)